# What do call this unit vector?

Tags: vectors, definition

Just a quick question.

I have a unit vector
$$e_i = [a_1,\ldots,a_i, \ldots]$$
and all the elements of $e_i$ are zero except $a_i$ and $a_i$ = 1.

What do we call such unit vectors (I mean, is there a specific terminology)? Do we call them $i^{th}$ basis vector?

Thanks

Comment: do you mean "**Why** do we call this unit vector"? If this is your question, then the answer is that a unit vector is a vector $v$ such that $\|v\|=1$. Note that there are norms for which the $i^{th}$ basis vector is not a unit vector. Take for example $\|v\|=2\|v\|_2$ where $\|v\|_2$ is the euclidean norm.

Comment: no, I just want to know if we have a specific word/terminology for such vectors.

Comment: Maybe “$i$-th *canonical* basis vector” then, as there are many other bases. Also, you just define $\mathbf e_i$ as you did here (but maybe more concise e. g. $(\mathbf e_i)_j = \delta_{ij}$) and call them simply “$\mathbf e_i$” below when needed. :)

Comment: I’m not well versed in this, so I will refrain from answering, but I believe that unit vectors and basis vectors are not synonymous. I would call it the $i$th unit vector, the $i$-dimension unit vector, or the unit vector in the $i$th direction.

Comment: @arseniiv, are they called as standard basis vectors?

Comment: @pkj To my knowledge, the less ambiguous name for $e_1,e_2,...$ is the "canonical basis" as mentioned by arseniiv.

Comment: This is the $i$th [standard basis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_basis) vector, usually denoted $e_i$.

Comment: @pkj For $K^n$ spaces, standard = canonical.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that this is a vector in either $\Bbb R^n$ or $\Bbb C^n$, the name $e_i$ is nearly universal in mathematics texts and papers. If you need words rather than a well-understood symbol, I would say, "The $i$th *standard basis vector*" or "the $i$th column of the identity matrix" (with the latter being hugely less common as a description). The "$i$th canonical basis vector", as proposed by @arseniiv, also seems like a decent choice. If the entries of $e_i$ are intended to be the $0$ and $1$ elements of an arbitrary field, I'm pretty sure that "standard" or "canonical" would suffice as well. I've read a fair number of mathematics papers over the years, and such a term would never surprise me, even for a vector space over $F_2$, the field of two elements, for instance.

If $0$ and $1$ are merely meant to be elements of a *ring*, then "vector" is the wrong word, for $n$-tuples of elements of a ring don't form a vector space (unless you've specified some way of combining an underlying field with an element of the ring to define "scalar multiplication").